# Switching between datasets in D3.js is showing unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to be able to switch between two datasets using D3.js. When I switch I want the old dataset to fade out while at the same time the new dataset fades in.

I have been hacking around on this code for some time now but im not getting the behavior I want. Se the following fiddle and try clicking on the text Dataset1 and Dataset2.

For example when I first click Dataset1 things work ok, but when I later click Dataset2 things im not getting all of Dataset2 values. If I now click Dataset1 again nothing happens and i have to dubble click to get things working. Also im never able to get all nine elements of Dataset2 to show up.

What am I missing?

```
var dataset1 = [1,2,3,4],
    dataset2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

update = function(newDataset){
    var allArrows = svg.selectAll(".arrow"),
        addNew; 

    addNew = function (){
            allArrows
            .data(newDataset)
            .enter()
            .append("line")
            .attr({
                opacity : 0,
                "stroke-width" : 1,
                stroke : "blue",
                class : "arrow",
                x1 : 10,
                y1 : function (d, i) { return 10 * i + 10 },
                x2 : 50,
                y2 : function (d, i) { return 10 * i + 10}
            })
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr({
                opacity : 1
            });
    });

    if ( !allArrows.empty() ) {
        allArrows
        .data([])
        .exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("opacity", 0);
        .remove();
        addNew();
    }
    else {
        addNew();
    }
    return chart;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/favetelinguis/pWqLL/1/

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work for me.

Comment: No you are correct, dont know why that is? It is working fine in my local browser Chrome. I have updated the code now so try again otherwise see if it is working on you local system...

Comment: The reason that there are elements left over is the transition you're using when exiting the data. The code to add the new lines takes those into account and therefore adds fewer than you'd expect. It works fine without the transition: http://jsfiddle.net/pWqLL/2/

Comment: yes but why is that? It is strange i have tried in every way to delete the old elements before adding new once but i just can't get them to go away.

Comment: That's because they are not deleted immediately (only at the end of the transition), but you're running the code to add the new elements immediately. In your code, you're even saving the selection you've made earlier.

Comment: I have tried using .each('end, ...) and do my adding there but still I get the same problem. I have tried to put my .remove statement both before and after .each and that makes no difference. Im stuck with this code.